How to change the appearance of just one button that is part of a larger class?
I would like to hide the save button in a Vue Modal, but when I access the button like so,


.btn.btn-primary {
    display: none;
}



It changes the appearance of every .btn-primary. It doesn't work to specify .modal on the styling because I have other modals that will also lose their buttons. If I use <style scoped> nothing is changed. Additionally, I have tried using the b-modal methods, but they do not work because my modal is utilizing a different set of standards and is not a b-modal. Does anyone have any ideas that I haven't tried or a better way to implement css to hide the save button?
The Modal HTML:


<template>
    <modal class="modal" :modal-id="modalId" :title="modalTitle" :preloader="preloader" @close-modal="closeModal" :ok-disabled="true">
        <template slot="body">
            <app-overlay-loader v-if="preloader" />
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <label class="description">
                        <div class="font-weight-bold"> {{ $t('Description') }} </div>
                        <span class="fs-6 text-secondary"> Articulos de accion que se complo hoy </span>
                        <div class="mt-2"> {{ description }}</div>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row align-items-center col-sm-4">
                    <label class="location">
                        <div class="font-weight-bold mb-4"> {{ $t('Ubicación') }} </div>
                        <div class=""> {{ location }}</div>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </template>
    </modal>
</template>




This doesn't work unless you assign modal-id to the HTML attribute id
An easy way to approach this is to either assign it to the id like :id="modal-id"
and then using CSS
#modal-id .btn.btn-primary {
    display: none;
}

or attach a custom modal class like :class="'modal ' + modal-class"
and then using CSS to target that modal class
.modal-class .btn.btn-primary {
    display: none;
}


Thank you for attempting this problem. For some reason no change is made in the CSS with either of these changes.

@Trinky, just to be sure, in the CSS, you would replace modal-id or modal-class with the actual name you're passing. If it's still not working, then I suspect the CSS file is somehow not loading? I think we need some more context on your setup and anything else that might affect this modal.

Yes, for example I have :modal-id="infoModal" so I would call #infoModal .btn.btn-primary. I honestly don't think there is anything else that would effect this modal, that's part of why I'm baffled. I'm wondering if it maybe has to do with defaults for . I am thinking about just reconfiguring it to a b-modal.

Can you setup a jsfiddle or any other platform with your issue? Would allow us to debug
